# Getting Datatables and Sparklines to play nice together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, datatables, sparklines

Im currently trying to get [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) and the [Sparklines](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) packages to work together kind of like below:

[(This stuff is all written in R however)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2yJs.png)

I realize my issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875081/properly-rendering-sparklines-in-a-datatable)... However, even after looking at some of the code and adapting it to my own, I was only able to render one or the other.. either the data from my server on the chart or the sparklines rendered with all data missing - never both together...

Here's the code

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table Name</th>
            <th>Column Name</th>
            <th>Rule</th>
            <th>Current</th>
            <th>Minimum</th>
            <th>Maximun</th>
            <th>Median</th>
            <th>Mean</th>
            <th>Sparkline</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The HTML above and the JS below..

```
<script>

    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    CURRENT_JOB = "{{ job_requested }}";
    data = {{ data|safe}}



$(function() {

       $('.js-typeahead').typeahead({
         order: "asc",
         source: {
           groupName: {
             // Array of Objects / Strings
             data: {{jobs|safe}}
           }
         },
         callback: {
           onInit: function() {
                $('#table_id').DataTable({
                   data:{{ data|safe}},
                    columns: [
                        {data: 'table_name'},
                        {data: 'col_name'},
                        {data: 'rule'},
                        {data: 'current'},
                        {data: 'min'},
                        {data: 'max'},
                        {data: 'median'},
                        {data: 'mean'},
                    ],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "aTargets": [8],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                             // since data is an array of values [1,2,3,4]
                            data = data.toString()
                            return '<span class="spark">' + data + '</span>'
                        }
                    }
                ],
               "drawCallback": (oSettings) => {
                   console.log('callback')
                  $('.spark:not(:has(canvas))').sparkline('html', {
                      type: 'line',
                      minSpotColor: 'red',
                      maxSpotColor: 'green',
                      spotColor: false
                  });
              }
               });
           }
         }
       });


   });
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I need the `columns: []` to point my JSON data to the right columns in the table but I also need to point one of the keys in my data object to the sparkline itself and then call the `.sparkline()`

Also my data object structure that im getting from the server kinda looks like this:

```
 data = { 
      'table_name': cow,
      'col_name' : cow_col,
      'rule' : cow_col,
      ..etc, etc..
      'data4spark: [1,2,3,4]

   }
```

I really appreciate anyones feedback/help! Thanks! ❤️

Answer (score 1):

Got it. This always happen every time I post a stackoverflow question, but I think i'd be stuck for a few days if I didn't post so..

Anyways, after reading the docs for a few hours -- The `aoColumnDefs` is a selector that can select an entire row in the table (if it's **already created** in the HTML) and that was wrong in my code above.. The `aTargets` is the parameter that you pass in the index of the column and the `mRender` is the call back function that you call right before it spits out whatever to the screen (it can modify the data beforehand for that specific col)

The diff is that I sent the code to the HTML using the `columns` and then I targeted the whole col to attatch the  tags on and sent them over

Posting my code in hopes this saves someone time

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
                   data:{{ data|safe}},
                    columns: [
                        {data: 'table_name'},
                        {data: 'col_name'},
                        {data: 'rule'},
                        {data: 'current'},
                        {data: 'min'},
                        {data: 'max'},
                        {data: 'median'},
                        {data: 'mean'},
                        {data: 'data'},

                    ],
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "aTargets": [8],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                             // since data is an array of values [1,2,3,4]
                            return '<span class="spark">' + data + '</span>'
                        }
                    }
                ],
               "drawCallback": (oSettings) => {
                   console.log('callback');
                   console.log($('.spark:not(:has(canvas))'))
                  $('.spark:not(:has(canvas))').sparkline('html', {
                      type: 'line',
                      minSpotColor: 'red',
                      maxSpotColor: 'green',
                      spotColor: false
                  });
              }
               });
```

Comment: I found your posting helpful and added an additional question to it at https://stackoverflow.com/q/65499745/12417398 - fyi . Thanks for sharing this...